# Regexp pattern to split where clause

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regexp pattern but doesn't work as I want.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\w[\w\d]* \s*[<>!=like]{1,4}\s* ( \?|\w[\w\d]*|(\w[\w\d]*)*((?<PR>\()|(?<-PR>\))|[^()])+ )", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled);

MatchCollection mc = re.Matches("per_name != 'John' && per_name != 'Peter'");

foreach (Match m in mc) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);        
}
```

I want to my code's output as:

```
per_name != 'John'
per_name != 'Peter'
```

Comment: What are the requirements? Just [`\w+\s*!=\s*'[^']*'`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%2b%5cs*!%3d%5cs*%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27&i=per_name+!%3d+%27John%27+%26%26+per_name+!%3d+%27Peter%27) could be used given the current unclear question.

Comment: I want to my code works on all combinations of possible SQL where clauses.

Comment: If you just want to split where clause, you could also use [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms228388.aspx). Use `&&` and `||`as delimiter and store them in an array. Now call `whereClauseText.Split(delimiter)`. This gives you an array with the elements from your where clause.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is good idea :)

Comment: @Urknecht: I suggest you post the suggestion. I do not believe there can be a better idea for this task.

Comment: Where is the string sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I'm posting my comment:

It would be easier to split your where clause via [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms228388.aspx). Your delimiter can be `&&`,`||`,`AND`,`OR`, `whatever`. Here is an example:

```
string whereClauseText = "per_name != 'John' && per_name != 'Peter'";
string[] operators =  new string[] {'&&','||','AND','OR'};

string[] clauses = whereClauseText.Split(operators, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string clause in clauses)
{
    Console.WriteLine(clause);
}
```

You shoul also take a look at the [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms131448.aspx), so that you can play arount with the `StringSplitOptions`.

Comment: What can do when string whereClauseText = "per_name != 'John' && per_name != 'Pe&&ter'"; ?

Comment: well, I'm not quite sure if this would be a valid where clause and I'm also not sure if you are using SqlConneciton commands or standard SQL, so its hard to tell. You could still use `whereClauseText.Split()` and just check if the elements in the string `clause`contrains SQL Operators like `!=`,`=`,`>`, etc. If it contains operators you got a valid clause, else just connect the `clause` with the next element until the connected string contains an operator. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @codeator if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.